# Mime parser & composer for C language?

Tags: iphone, c, mime

I am not going to use C++ or Java, but I can not find a MIME C library. Does somebody know?

Answer (score 1):

How about [libgmime](http://spruce.sourceforge.net/gmime/)? (It's C, but uses glib).

Comment: @iamjiex: What libc does iPhone use then?

Comment: glib != glibc.  Does glib really not compile on iphone? It appears to be available on OS X...

Answer (score 0):

There is [Streaming Event MIME Message Parser in C](http://eng03.barracudanetworks.com/projects/libmime.html). But the library has not mime composer part.